# поиск соответсвий используя сортировку слиянием

Tags: java

Условие - ввод с клавиатуры, первоя строка содержит число 1<=n<=10^5(10 в степени 5), следующая строка содержит массив A[1 ... n], который содержит натуральные числа не больше чем 10^9(10 в степени 9). Посчитать количество пар индексов подходящих под условие: 1 ≤ i < j ≤ n для каждых A[i]>A[j]. Например, массив [2, 4, 1, 3, 5] имеет 3 пары подходящие под условие: (2, 1), (4, 1), (4, 3). Задание идет в теме Merge sort (сортировка слиянием) и предполагает что я как то изменю код сортировки для подсчета необходимой величины (через for решить не удается, т.к. не укладываюсь по времени); далее код

```
import java.util.*;

public class stepik {
static long count = 0L;

public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
//        int size = in.nextInt();
//        int[] arr = new int[size];
//        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
//            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
//        }
    int[] arr = {2,4,1,3,5};


    mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.length);
    System.out.println(count);

}
public static void mergeSort(int[] array, int leftIncl, int rightExcl) {

    if (rightExcl <= leftIncl + 1) {
        return;
    }

    int middle = leftIncl + (rightExcl - leftIncl) / 2;

    mergeSort(array, leftIncl, middle);
    mergeSort(array, middle, rightExcl);
    merge(array, leftIncl, middle, rightExcl);
}
public static void  merge(int[] array, int left, int middle, int right) {

    int i = left;
    int j = middle;
    int k = 0;
    int[] temp = new int[right - left];


    while (i < middle && j < right) {
        if (array[i] > array[j]) {
            temp[k] = array[i];
            i++;
            count++;
        } else {
            temp[k] = array[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
}
}
```

я вставил счетчик в цикл while, изменив условие if под задание, но что я что то не то считаю...

Comment: да, вопрос тот же, там дан в качестве ответа теоретический материал, который внес немного ясности;  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168604/inversion-count-using-divide-and-conquer) помогло решить задачу, т.к. там дан рабочий вариант кода который я смог адаптировать для решения задачи.